# Event for creating a new product attribute

Tags: attributes, event-observer

Is there a Magento event for when a new product attribute is created?

I have tried these with no luck:

- `catalog_product_save_attribute_before`
- `save_attribute_before`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max,please try `catalog_entity_attribute_save_before` instead of  `catalog_product_save_attribute_before` and `save_attribute_before`

Comment: Yeh I will :P It said I had to wait 3 mins.